# Tabulation order in Display Suite

Tags: display-suite

Display suite (http://drupal.org/project/ds) allows you to modify the form display appliyng template layouts.
But if i chose (say) a 3 column layout, with say 6 field, the tab order is per column and not per field weight.

example:

left-----middle---right

field1 - field2 -field3

field4 - field5 -field6

if i press tab, the focus shift from field 1 to field 4, and not on field 2 as expected.
 it's possibile to set a tab order per row and/or per field weight?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this if you use something like javascript or jQuery and using the tabindex attribute.  Take a look at the below link at Stackoverflow as an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894539/how-to-set-tab-order-in-jquery

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate more. The answer might not be acceptable in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Renderable elements](https://drupal.org/project/rel) module.

You can also see a demo [here](http://youtu.be/rSgd91tZSEc).